# Calculating SUM of price between two dates in different months

Tags: php, sql

So im trying to create a monthly report for an apartment based on bookings.
I have a table called bookings with ID, arrival_date, departure_date, price_per_night.

| ID | arrival_date | departure_date | price_per_night |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 29.1.2023 | 2.2.2023 | 50 |

Everything works fine untill a date is between two months. For example:

arrival_date = '29.1.2023', departure_date = '2.2.2023' and price: 50.

So in my monthly report i would like to add the three nights that were in january to january(150) and the one day in February to add it to February(50).

So how can I calculate this?

This is how i get the SUM of the price:

I use the previous month, because i want to automate the creation of the monthly report.

```
$date = date('m') - 1; //previous month

$sql = "SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(departure_date, arrival_date) * price_per_night) sum_price FROM bookings WHERE MONTH(arrival_date) = $date
```

When I run this I get the SUM of the whole booking so 200 (4 nights * 50).

I would like to get the SUM only for the 3 nights in January so 150 ( 3 nights * 50)

And when I run the program the next month in March I would like to get the remaining 50 from the booking added to February (1 night * 50).

Comment: What exact DMS you have?

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code and xampp

Comment: As long as the maximum time span is two months, this wouldn't be too difficult (e.g. Feb 3 till March 20 = Feb 3 till last day of Feb + first day of March till March 20). This could be got with a union query (month 1 union month 2). With time spans covering more months, however, you'll need a recursive query to generate the monthly data.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? MySQL or SQL Server maybe? `DATEDIFF` and `MONTH` are proprietary functions, not working in every DBMS. `FROM 'bookings'` is invalid SQL. Single quotes denote string literals, not names.

Comment: Im using MySQL. I changed the 'bookings' that works now, but I still don't know how to calculate it correctly.

Comment: And yes the maximum span is two months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL the later date must be first before the arruvak date, ti get a positive datediff.

as you only wants night, the math is simple subtract 1 from the date differenz

```
SELECT SUM((DATEDIFF(departure_date,arrival_date) - 1) * `price_per_night`) sum_price
  FROM `bookings`
WHERE MONTH(arrival_date) = 1
```

| sum_price |
| --- |
| 150 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aSj8NVRk)

You can adept it for one night or evern for multiple Month
see

```
SELECT MONTH(arrival_date), YEAR(arrival_date), SUM(
  CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(departure_date,arrival_date) > 1 THEN
                     (DATEDIFF(departure_date,arrival_date) - 1) 
  ELSE 1 END * `price_per_night`) sum_price
  FROM `bookings`
  GROUP BY MONTH(arrival_date), YEAR(arrival_date)
```

| MONTH(arrival_date) | YEAR(arrival_date) | sum_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023 | 150 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/idHWy9n0)

Comment: Thanks i changed the order of the arrival and departure date, but I still haven't figured out how to do the math for each month. This math only works for this example. If I had a booking that was only for one night it wouldn't even get calcucalated because of the -1.

Comment: i add another query, you need tp adept my forst query to fit your requirements, but the second considers one nihzers and will select all form every month an year

Comment: Thank you so much. This almost works perfectly. The only problem is if I change the departure day to lets say 2023-02-03 or any other day in february the SUM should stay the same 150 for January.

Comment: Add another column, the database can't understand logic, itis unsorted and doesn't "remember" as long as you haven't some kind of programmed logic into it. also please only one question at the time, ou changed the question already